# SELECT an image with NO form submission just populate appropriate hidden field

Tags: javascript, forms

UPDATE... I've spent more time trying to get the code snippets into this question, than the whole project is worth.  Trust me that there is a hidden field called menu.  The javascript below takes care of displaying the alt of each picture when clicked.  I need the src to load into a hidden field called menu.

We are trying to create a single page to select menu items on a form and THEN with the other contact info submit the form.  Below is just the code relating to the pictures.

Currently, using "onclick" the customer clicks on an image and the full description then shows up underneath (javascript). I want to fill a hidden form field with a value to reflect the menu selection (which picture did they click).

As the only attributes on an image are src and alt I can pass the src in the form and process when the form is submitted.  But I can't seem to get the "src" to populate the hidden menu field "menu."   I'm open to better ways to do this.

Thanks in advance

```
    function myFunction(imgs) {
         var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
         var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
         var imgSRC = imgs.src;
         imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
         expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";  
         document.getElementById("menu").value = imgSRC;
}
```

Comment: There is no element here with id = "menu".

Comment: I had a time getting the code section up.  There really is a hidden field "menu" in the code.

Comment: Using JSFiddle, I created this example of a stripped down version that ignores the part that isn't relevant (the image text and expanding). In this link, it shows your code works. I also used a text box instead of hidden to show it working as changing both values use the same code. https://jsfiddle.net/3ar6cxno/

Comment: For some reason, I got getElementsByName to work, but not getElementsByID  and the field has an id and a name properly...  But thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `getElementsByID()` is not a valid method.